# Как передать значения одного поля другому? с помощью jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Код считает сумму, и нужно чтоб он эту сумму автоматически записывал в другое поле

```
var budget = document.budget.value;                  
var sum=0;
$('table tr').each(function(){
    $(this)
    .find('input[type=text]')
    .each(function(){
        sum+=parseInt($(this).val());
    });
    $(this).find('td:last').html(sum);    
    sum=0;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно правильно использовать `.each()`, поэтому [внимательно читаем статью](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F_%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0)

Там четко написано, что метод имеет один вариант использования:

> .each(callback(index, domElement))

У вас в колбэк не передается никаких параметров.
Значит нам нужно только немного переписать код. Разметку сделал свою, но принцип там понятен:

```js
function getSum() {

  var $target = $('.term'),
    sum = 0;
//тот кусок, который вам нужен
  $target.each(function(idx, item) {
    sum += parseInt($(this, item).val()) || 0;
  });
  
   $('.sumInput').val(sum);
  $('.sum').text(sum);

}

document.getElementById('getSum').addEventListener('click', getSum, false);
```

```css
input {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="term" placeholder="Слагаемое" />
<input type="text" class="term" placeholder="Слагаемое" />
<input type="text" class="term" placeholder="Слагаемое" />
<input type="text" class="term" placeholder="Слагаемое" />
<input type="button" id="getSum" value="Посчитать" />
<input type="text" class="sumInput" placeholder="Сумма" />
<div class="sum"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял вопрос.

1. Вы объявили переменную `var sum = 0;` вне функции `.each`, поэтому сумма не обнуляется.
2. На каждый `input` нужно навесить событие, отслеживающее изменение.

Пример: https://jsfiddle.net/wn9k26qw/1/

```js
function rowSumm($row) {
  var summ = 0;
  $row.find('input[type=text]')
    .each(function() {
      var val = parseInt($(this).val());
      summ += isNaN(val) ? 0 : val;
    });
  $row.find('td:last').html(summ);
}

$('table tr input[type=text]').keyup(function() {
  var $row = $(this).parents('tr');
  rowSumm($row);
});

$('table tr').each(function() {
  rowSumm($(this))
});
```

```css
input {
  max-width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Field 1</th>
    <th>Field 2</th>
    <th>Field 3</th>
    <th>Field 4</th>
    <th>Summ</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value="1"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="2"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="3"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="4"></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value="1"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="2"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="3"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="4"></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value="1"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="2"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="3"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="4"></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```